# Can't use my php variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php variable. Then with JS on a buttonclick I have to open a link containing that variable. According to other topics this has to work, but it's not. Nothing happens if I click on it.

```
<?php
    $id = 'string';
?>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
   function openBox() {
       php_var = <?php echo $id; ?>;
       targetURL = "other_page.php?id=" + php_var
       theBox = window.open(targetURL, 'theResults', 'status=0, toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, resizable=0, scrollbars=1, width=600,height=680,left=10,top=10');
   }
</SCRIPT>
```

***EDIT**:
OK, so I forgot `var`, `'` and `;`.
The modified code (below) now opens the desired site, but the var is empty. If I simply echo it in php, it has it's value.

```
<?php
    $id = 'string';
?>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
   function openBox() {
       php_var = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
       targetURL = "other_page.php?id=" + php_var
       theBox = window.open(targetURL, 'theResults', 'status=0, toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, resizable=0, scrollbars=1, width=600,height=680,left=10,top=10');
   }
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Hint: Don't try to guess what your resulting JavaScript looks like or how it behaves.  Actually *look at it* and *debug it* in your browser.  "Nothing happens if I click" isn't debugging.  Your browser's JavaScript console is most certainly telling you what the problem is, don't ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark the question as resolved. However we prefer not to do it in questions here, so the question/answer format can be preserved. I've added an answer below - you can do that in future yourself, as we welcome self-answers here.

Comment: (I've voted to close, as I am not sure the php/html extension confusion will be of utility to a wide audience in the future. Nevertheless, pleased you fixed your problem!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posted on behalf of OP*.

Solution: I had html extension instead of php, so that the php code haven't been executed.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add quotes and `var`

```
var php_var = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
var targetURL = "other_page.php?id=" + php_var
var theBox = window.open(targetURL, 'theResults', 'status=0, toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, resizable=0, scrollbars=1, width=600,height=680,left=10,top=10');
```

Comment: Please check the post, I updated it.

Comment: I don't understand the `If I simply echo it in php, it has it's value.`

Comment: `echo $id;` works, but it's not appearing in the targetURL

Comment: If you add quotes it doesn't work ? That's what you mean ?

Comment: No, the problem is I would expect the URL to be `other_page.php?id=string` but it's simply `other_page.php?id=`.

Comment: Like the `$id` string was empty.

Comment: Try to add a `console.log("php_var= " + php_var)` just after the declaration ... and check console output

Comment: I'm an idiot. Anyway thank you for your help, I wouldn't catch it without your support. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

what about changing the line

```
php_var = <?php echo $id; ?>;
```

to

```
php_var = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
```

?

are you absolutely sure that $id is defined within your php script and that it has not an empty string value?

Comment: I am absolutely sure. It's defined just like in the above piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotation marks for a string, otherwise script thinks you are assigning variable named *string* to *php_var*:

```
php_var = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
```

Also, you missed a colum at the end of this line:

```
targetURL = "other_page.php?id=" + php_var;
```